# Getting From List key and value to put default values in Select2 4.0.3

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller, jquery-select2

i have a list with ID and Value and i want select2 to take Values and show in select when page is loaded.

here is my select2 for now

```
var matchingClause = $("#ExistedEntryList").val();
    $.each(matchingClause, function (key, value) {
        $('#tags').select2({
            data: { id: key, text: value },
            tags: true
        });
        $('#tags').val(data);
    });`
```

my select is

```html
        <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="tags" style="width: 400px;" value="@Model.EntryTagNames" name="tags[]">
```

and lastly here is my controller when i put data in list

```
       //დოკუმენტის ტიპის და ქვეტიპების სახელების წამოღება.
        List<Select2ListItem> list = new List<Select2ListItem>();
        var entriesViewModel = new EntryViewModel();

        var entryTags = _tagService.GetTagsByEntryId(id);
        foreach (var tag in entryTags)
        {

            list.Add(new Select2ListItem
            {
                id = tag.Id.ToString(),
                text = tag.Name
            });
        }


    entriesViewModel.ExistedEntryList = list;
        return View(entriesViewModel);
```

I want this List values to be shown in select2 as tags and when i post there to be Ids. any suggestions ?

Comment: when you `console.log(key + value)` you got the correct keys and values??

Answer (score 0):

- `select2` work with rendered `<select>` .. This means you can make your default structure for the `<select>` then apply the plugin to it ..

This is how it can be done in js

```js
var matchingClause = {
  key1 : "value1",
  key2 : "value2",
  key3 : "value3",
  key4 : "value4"
};
$.each(matchingClause, function (key, value) {
    $('select#tags').append('<option value="'+value+'">'+ value +'</option>');
});
$('#tags').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a value'
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>

<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="tags" style="width: 400px;" name="tags[]"></select>
```

**Note:** I'm not expert in controller but if you have a way to append the options to the `<select>` with controller (maybe a way) then apply the plugin